# The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: magento-1.9

after adding SSL in my site i got warrning :
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the 
    response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
I have add below code in htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```